# How to run custom code in IntEnum class body

Tags: python, enums

I'm trying to generate the values that will go into a custom enum instead of using literals:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class Test(IntEnum):
    for i in range(3):
        locals()['ABC'[i]] = i
    del i
```

My desired output is three attributes, named `A`, `B`, `C`, with values 0, 1, 2, respectively. This is based on two expectations that I've come to take for granted about python:

1. The class body will run in an isolated namespace before anything else
2. `locals` during that run will refer to said isolated namespace

Once the body is done executing, I would expect the result to be not much different than calling `IntEnum('Test', [('A', 0), ('B', 1), ('C', 2)])` (which works just fine BTW).

Instead, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in Test
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 95, in __setitem__
    raise TypeError('Attempted to reuse key: %r' % key)
TypeError: Attempted to reuse key: 'i'
```

If I try doing the same with `class Test:` instead of `class Test(IntEnum):`, it works as expected. The traceback is showing the problem to be happening in `enum.py`. This contradicts my assumptions about how things work.

What is going on with this code, and how to I  create attributes in the local namespace of the class body *before* `IntEnum` can get to them?

**Background** The reason that I'm trying to create the enum this way is that the "real" values are a more complex tuple, and there is a `__new__` method defined to parse the tuple and assign some attributes to the individual enum objects. All that does not seem to be relevant to figuring out what is happening with the error and fixing it.

Comment: metaclasses most likely. These are "classes of a class", and can change the fundamental way class is executed. - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#enum-class-differences; https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses

Comment: @matszwecja. I'm fairly fluent with metaclasses, and that doesn't explain anything to me. The class body should still be executed as-is

Comment: @matszwecja. You got me thinking on the right track though. I bet it's the `__prepare__` method returning a read-only mapping or something: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace

Comment: Note that `for i in …` is an assignment on the class scope as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. Noted. That's why I have `del i` at the end there. The issue is likely that the `locals()` of an enum are `enum._EnumDict` vs the normal `dict` of a regular class.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/enum.py#L344
This here is worth checking

Comment: @matszwecja. Good call. Apparently dunders get ignored...

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Yeah, I thought that was in the docs -- it's definitely in the comments.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First, an explanation of what is happening. Before executing the class body, the metaclass's [`__prepare__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace) method is used to create the namespace. Normally, this is just a `dict`. However, [`enum.EnumType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.EnumType) uses a [`enum._EnumDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/enum.py#L344) class, which specifically prevents duplicate names from being added to the namespace. While this does not alter how the code in the class body is run, it does alter the namespace into which that code places names.

There are a couple of exceptions to the duplicate prevention, which offer potential solutions. First, the proper solution is to use the [`_ignore_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum._ignore_) sunder attribute. If it gets set first, the variable `i` can be used normally, and will not appear in the final class:

```
class Test(IntEnum):
    _ignore_ = ['i']

    for i in range(3):
        locals()['ABC'[i]] = i
```

Another, much hackier method is to use a dunder name, which will be ignored by the metaclass:

```
class Test(IntEnum):
    for __i__ in range(3):
        locals()['ABC'[__i__]] = __i__
    del __i__
```

While this solution is functional, it uses dunders, which are nominally reserved by the language, and an undocumented feature, both of which are bad.

Comment: The dunder method also leaves `__i__` in the namespace unless you `del` it -- but as you say, it's a bad idea -- just use `_ignore_`.

Comment: @EthanFurman. Thanks for the catch. I didn't notice it because it wasn't affecting the constants.